# How to use Storage Access Framework with MediaMuxer if Android API level less than 26

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sdcard

I'm creating a file to recording via Android MediaMuxer, and I want to store this file in any folder I specified in the removable SD card (Not only in the /Android/data/data/application).

I can use SAF (Storage Access Framework) to achieve it if the Android API level is above 26.

```
var fd: FileDesciptor? = null

for (permission in activity.contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions) {
    if (permission.uri.path == "path/to/file") {
        val docFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, permission.uri)!!.
                createFile("video/mp4", "test.mp4")
        fd = activity.contentResolver.
                openFileDescriptor(docFile!!.uri, "w")!!.
                fileDesciptor
        break
    }
}

val muxer = MediaMuxer(fd, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
```

But the file descriptor version constructor

```java
public MediaMuxer(@NonNull FileDescriptor fd, @Format int format) throws IOException
```

is not available if API level < 26.

There is only file path version

```java
public MediaMuxer(@NonNull String path, @Format int format) throws IOException
```

I can use.

But I can't get the real path with permission from SAF.

```
docFile.uri.path // this gives me a path with strange prefix.
```

So is there a way I can record a file via MediaMuxer in any folder I specified in the removable SD card if the Android API level is less than 26?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you and no any help.But there may have some workarounds.

You can record the file into internal storage and when the record end you may copy the record file into your removable SD using SAF